# Need help setting up VLAN

Tags: vlan

I'm quite new with networking. I need to set up this VLAN setup (shown below). I have a Media Converter Device (EDD). My trouble is I don't know how to setup VLAN.

I know the basics of VLAN (concepts). But I don't know how to set it up in a router/switch device.

[image]

This is the interface for the device I am working on:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the model of the media converter and the Cisco switch?

Comment: As previously requested you should provide the switch and media device models so you can be helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process is pretty straight forward.
1. identify the devices that need isolation- each VLAN per such device.
2. Remember VLANS are set up at the switch interface.
3. the switch interface links that have been configured with non native vlans (other than default) have to be trunk - VTP, ISL , etc
4. For communication between two devices in different VLAN's - if needed you will need a layer 3 device - router or SVI.
5, Router have no concept of VLANS, they operate at layer 3.
thus there is no configuration involved at the router.

For a more conceptual understanding about VLANS you may want to read about VLAN tags, switch forwarding table and switch virtual interfaces.